# Uploading a file to Facebook using Koala on Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, facebook-graph-api, koala

[I followed the following blogpost](http://horserumble.com/creating-facebook-events-with-koala#comment) to figure out how to create Facebook events remotely using my app.  I've been having problems loading the images from my app, however, because I do not have images stored locally on my app, they are stored in AWS.

> ```
>     @graph = Koala::Facebook::GraphAPI.new(@token)  
>     picture = Koala::UploadableIO.new(@event.photo.url(:small))
>     params = {
>         :picture => picture,
>         :name => 'Event name',
>         :description => 'Event descriptio
>         :start_time => datetime,
>        }
> ```

is the following code I am currently using to send pictures to Facebook when Facebook events are created on my app.  The problem is, however, that Rails is throwing the error: No such file or directory - http://s3.amazonaws.com/ColumbiaEventsApp/photos/21/small.jpeg?1312521889.

Does anybody who's more experienced with Rails development know if there is a way for me to treat a URL like a path to a file?  The UploadableIO class expects a path to a file, and I'm struggling to figure out if there's a way in Ruby to treat URL's like filepaths.  The way that photos stored on the app can be loaded to Facebook is as follows:

> picture = Koala::UploadableIO.new(File.open("PATH TO YOUR EVENT IMAGE"))

if that helps.

I appreciate any new insights into this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Koala 1.2.1 it's a very elegant solution. Here is sample code for creating an album and uploading to it from a remote, AWS link (btw this took about 30 lines in PHP w/ the PHP SDK!

```
@foo = Foo.find(params[:foo_id])        
albuminfo = @graph.put_object('me','albums', :name=>@foo.title)
album_id = albuminfo["id"]    
@graph.put_picture(@foo.remote_image_path,{}, album_id)
```

Comment: You can also ommit the album_id and it will create a default album for your app and post it there:
  @graph.put_picture(@foo.remote_image_path,{})

Comment: Yes- it defaults to the app name, so "my app" will create an album called "my app"

Comment: how do u do the same for events?

Comment: What about if you want to post a remote video(from AWS s3) to FB ? Facebook video uploading API not supporting public urls.

Answer (score 9):

Ok so I played around and figured out how to post pictures.

Basically what I did was use the 'open-uri' library to convert the image links into file objects, which can then be passed to UploadableIO and sent to Facebook.  This is the code that worked:

```
require 'open-uri'
OpenURI::Buffer.send :remove_const, 'StringMax' if OpenURI::Buffer.const_defined?('StringMax')
OpenURI::Buffer.const_set 'StringMax', 0
picture = Koala::UploadableIO.new(open(@event.photo.url(:small)).path, 'image')
params = {
  picture:     picture,
  name:        @event.name,
  description: @event.description,
  location:    @event.location,
  start_time:  datetime
}
@graph.put_object('me', 'events', params )
```

The OpenURI constant StringMax needed to be changed because the image files I was using were small enough that the files were being processed as Strings rather than File Objects.

Hope this helps anyone trying to fix this!

Comment: I've been at this for hours. You, sir, are a king among men.

Comment: This was extremely useful trying to figure out how to add a video captions file (.SRT) to a video using. Nothing worked until I passed the `captions_file` argument using: `Koala::UploadableIO.new( file_path, 'application/octet-stream' )`

Answer (score 1):

Facebook recently released an update that lets you post pictures using publicly accessible URLs (http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/526/).  The Koala library you're using supports that (https://github.com/arsduo/koala/blob/master/lib/koala/graph_api.rb#L102), so you should be able to post the pictures you're hosting on S3 without having to use OpenURI::Buffer.

Comment: here is updated link to the line that indicates this  https://github.com/arsduo/koala/blob/master/lib/koala/api/graph_api.rb#L243

Answer (score 1):

For Facebook [Ad Images](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-image), you unfortunately currently cannot do it by URL, thus:

```
require 'open-uri'
img_data = open(my_post.image.url :medium).read
img = graph.put_connections('act_X', 'adimages', bytes: Base64.encode64(img_data))
```